# Minilot and minilof not showing, to the contrary of minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I organize my thesis as a book, with three chapters. 
I use the `minitoc` package. Once I control for the number of star sections, the `minitoc` appears well in the chapter. 
But `minilot` and `minilof` are still invisible. 
Does anyone have any clue ?

MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}        
\dominitoc                      
\dominilot                      

\tableofcontents    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}
\listoftables   

\setcounter{mtc}{1}         % make minitoc appear
\chapter{article1}

\newpage
\minitoc
\minilot 
\newpage


\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla


\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table1}
\label{tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\hline
bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\hline\hline 
\end{tabular}           
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

If you compile the document, I expect to have on page 8 a list of tables after the mini table of contents.

Comment: Please post _one_ compilable piece of code instead of snippets going into each other. It makes life easier for (and increases the chance of) people wanting to help.

Comment: @campa I heard you. I just dropped some sections and the figure, so no list of figures any more, but it should be compilable.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\fakelistoftables` is missing, together with 3 compilation runs.

Please note that the `minitoc` package isn't updated since the death of its author, J. Drucbert in 2009.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}



\dominitoc                      
\dominilot                      

\tableofcontents    
\fakelistoftables   


\chapter{article1}

\minitoc
\minilot

\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla


\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table1}
\label{tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\hline
bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\hline\hline 
\end{tabular}           
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

[image]